# Android NFC scanning on home launcher app

Tags: android, kotlin, nfc, android-launcher

I have an android app set as the default launcher of the device with :

```
 <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 </intent-filter>
```

I also have a BaseActivity that every activity of my app extends where i register for NFC reading :

```
 override fun onResume() {
   super.onResume()
   val manager: NfcManager = getSystemService(Context.NFC_SERVICE) as NfcManager
   nfcAdapter = manager.defaultAdapter
   if (nfcAdapter == null) {
      showMessage("NFC not supported on this device")
         return;
   }
   // Check if NFC is enabled
   if (nfcAdapter?.isEnabled == false) {
        showMessage("Enable NFC")

   }
   val options = Bundle()
       options.putInt(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_READER_PRESENCE_CHECK_DELAY, 200)

      nfcAdapter?.enableReaderMode(
           this,
           this,
           NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A or
           NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_SKIP_NDEF_CHECK ,
           options
        );
    }
```

If i restart the device and the app launches as the device launcher, when I scan a NFC it shows the "New Tag Collected" view from com.android.apps.tag.

After dismissing that and scanning again it works fine. Any idea on why that might happen.

Also my device is rooted so if anyone has an adb idea please say so.

I tried debugging, and logging and the onResume is called fine and the NFC adapter is enabled correctly, just the onTagReceived is not called the first time after restart. I also tried using

```
enableForegroundDispatch
```

but still the same

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NFCAdpater.enableReaderMode(...) doesn't work consistently if booting in Kiosk mode activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61142449/nfcadpater-enablereadermode-doesnt-work-consistently-if-booting-in-kiosk-m)

Comment: As with Kiosk mode probably being the launch app, when started your App might not be considered to being in the foreground, so both foreground API won't trigger for your App. Have you also consider adding a manifest NFC tech filter? that will start/bring to foreground your app.