# Android 8.1 - onNewIntent() not working after system reboot

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an Android 8.1 tablet where I've developed a Kiosk application. Currently, I'm facing an issue where `onNewIntent()` doesn't work after a system reboot.

When the system reboots, I run a command like `adb shell am start com.android.settings` and then return to my application, or close my app `onNewIntent()` starts working again.

When I reinstall the application using Android Studio, `onNewIntent()` works.

So, the problem only occurs after the system is rebooted, `onNewIntent()` doesn't discover NFC tags anymore in my application (although the device still plays the sound of the NFC tag being detected).

**Android code**

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if (nfcAdapter != null) {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
        nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, null, null);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if (nfcAdapter != null) nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}   

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "NFC TAG DISCOVERED.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // ...
    }
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

in case it's required, this is how i turn my device into kiosk mode:

`.\adb -s 192.168.2.170:5555 shell dpm set-device-owner com.crezzur.dienstplannerprodvx/.DeviceOwnerReceiver`

```
private void setupDeviceOwner(Context context) {
    DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    ComponentName adminComponentName = DeviceOwnerReceiver.getComponentName(this);
    if (dpm.isDeviceOwnerApp(getPackageName())) {
        //startLockTask();
        dpm.setLockTaskPackages(adminComponentName, new String[]{
                "com.crezzur.dienstplannerprodvx",
                "com.android.settings",
        });
        dpm.setKeyguardDisabled(adminComponentName, true);
        dpm.setStatusBarDisabled(adminComponentName, true);
    }
    dpm.isDeviceOwnerApp(getPackageName());
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NFCAdpater.enableReaderMode(...) doesn't work consistently if booting in Kiosk mode activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61142449/nfcadpater-enablereadermode-doesnt-work-consistently-if-booting-in-kiosk-m)

Comment: @Andrew i have looked into it and it does not seem to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, but it's more of a "messy" solution. If anyone has a better suggestion, I'm definitely willing to consider it.

My messy solution is to listen for RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED and then immediately open the settings app followed by my application. This way, the NfcAdapter will still works after a system reboot without any manual intervention.

**Adding following code in AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<application ... />
    <receiver
        android:name=".BootCompletedReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

**Adding following code in BootCompletedReceiver.class**

```
public class BootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "DEVICE START-UP COMPLETED.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // START Settings app
            Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
            settingsIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(settingsIntent);

            // START MainActivity
            Intent startAppIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            startAppIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(startAppIntent);

        }
    }
}
```